# Finding a the smallest partial order containing $R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $R$ be a relation on $\Bbb N$ defined by $(x, y) ∈ R$ iff there is a prime $p$ such that $y = px$. Describe in words the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closures of $R$, denoted by $r$, $s$ and $t$, respectively.

(a) What is the smallest partial order containing $R$?

(b) Using the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive closures, express the smallest equivalence relation containing an arbitrary relation.

I have tried to approach this problem many ways, but I cannot figure it out. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you do it for the case of just one prime, say $2$?  What does that relation look like?  You have $1R2, 2R4, 3R6,$ etc.  What do you have to add to make it reflexive, symmetric, or transitive?

Comment: I would have to add 2R1 4R2 6R3 1R1 2R2 3R3 4R4 6R6

Comment: You were asked separately for each of reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  Reflexive just requires $xRx$, so you need to add $1R1,2R2,$ and so on.  Any reflexive relation must include the identity and any relation can be made reflexive by adding the identity.  Yes, you need $2R1,4R2,$ and so on but not $2R2$ and $4R4$ for symmetric.  Transitive?

Comment: Ah I see my apologies. Then for transitive you would need to add 1R4

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Then you need $1R8, 1R16, 2R8, 2R16$ and so on.  Then a partial order is just transitive and antisymmetric.  We are already antisymmetric, so making it transitive is enough (and doesn't spoil the antisymmetry) to get a partial order.

Comment: But isn't that just for one case? Where p is 2? This is what confuses me the most about this problem. It is that there is a case for each p. Now we have given the smallest possible partial order if p is 2

Comment: Yes, I suggested working with one prime to make it easier.  Now we have to take the union over all the primes.  So instead of just $1R2,2R4,3R6$ you have $1Rp, 2R2p, 3R3p,$etc.  You also get $pRpq$ and $qRpq$ for $p,q$ primes.

Comment: I kind of see where you are coming from, but I am still a little confused :(

Comment: You are saying that the smallest partial order is the set of pairs of the p and p times another prime number AND that other prime number with p times that other prime number?

Comment: It is larger than that.  I gave those examples, but you have to keep going.  Because of transitivity, you will eventually get to needing $aRb$ if $a|b$ because there will be a chain of divisibilities one prime at a time to get from $a$ to $b$